# RecyclerView inside AppBarLayout is not scrollable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-scroll

I am using [Material Search View](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView). But It doesn't work when I use CoordinatorLayout as Root element and RecyclerView (SearchView - RecyclerView is child of custom view `com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView`) inside AppBarLayout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/container"
                                             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Irrelevant stuff -->
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbarlayout"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/search_layover_bg"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/theme_primary"/>

           <com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.MaterialSearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/theme_primary"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```